# 2D EWT (Empirical Wavelet Transform) in Python

Tags: python

I have been trying to decompose an image (2D signal) using one of function in signal processing known as Empirical Wavelet transform (2D EWT).

I have successfully decomposed the image using Discrete wavelet Transform, but for the better alternative i want to choose 2D EWT, but i am not able to find any fuction which i can use to perform the 2D EWT in **Python** in which i could split the image into 5 sub-band images

The documentation for 1D signal decomposition for Empirical Wavelet Transform is here https://github.com/vrcarva/ewtpy

Please help me

There is the documentation for 2D EWT in matlab, but i am familiar with Python but i am not able to find one, please help me